# Unity, ML-Agents "'Actionbuffers' could not be found" error

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

Recently I've been struggling with the ML-Agents Unity error - "*error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Actionbuffers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*". I've downloaded the latest package version of ML-Agents through Unity's Package Manager, also trying to download package through git URL. Nothings worked for me and I haven't been able to find help on the internet.

Here is the small bit of code I have so far plus the error message on Unity:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. deleted the script. redid it. it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code provided, the issue is that they forgot to add "using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;".
This is the lib that includes the ActionBuffers.

I did a quick check, and I could replicate the error if I omitted "using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;" and it was solved by adding "using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;"